# MYSQL: Adding and updating, conditionally, a temp colum into a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a tagging system.

I have a table of tags, and another full of items that are tagged consisting of the tagged items ID and the ID of the tag.

I am writing a fetch script that will give the data to generate some checkboxes so I can easily visualize/edit the tags for a given item.

I had the idea to add a temporary value called checked and then on the condition that a supplied Item ID was present in the tagged table (it has this tag) then set the temp check value to true in my table.

```
SELECT t.name AS name, t.id AS id, '0' AS checked  FROM tags t IF( id IN (SELECT DISTINCT tag_id FROM tagged WHERE workshop_id = $id) UPDATE t SET checked='1'
```

It just throws a generic sql error and doesn't work.  I don't have enough experience to know if this is a really bad idea, or even its its doable.  Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can we have simplified examples of your two tables, and a few rows of example data in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `UPDATE`, you can use the `CASE` expression to test whether `tags.id` found in `tagged` table or not, and put that in a temporary column `checked`, something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id AS id,
  t1.name AS name, 
  CASE WHEN t2.tag_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Checked
FROM tags AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM tagged
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.tag_id;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4139a/4)

This will give you something like this:

```
| ID | NAME | CHECKED |
-----------------------
|  1 |    a |       1 |
|  2 |    b |       0 |
|  3 |    c |       1 |
|  4 |    d |       0 |
```

---

### Update:

If you want to add a condition to the `tagged` table like `WHERE workshop_id = 26`, add it in the subquery not to the `LEFT JOIN` condition, like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id AS id,
  t1.name AS name, 
  CASE WHEN t2.tag_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Checked
FROM tags AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM tagged
   WHERE workshop_id = 26
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.tag_id;
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3e5d/2)

Comment: `SELECT 
  t1.id AS id,
  t1.name AS name, 
  CASE WHEN t2.workshop_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Checked
FROM tags AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM tagged
) AS t2 ON "26" = t2.workshop_id;`

This is very close to what I want, but I need to filter it out based on an external id ...I tried hardcoding "26" but it just generates a huge table....does your solution still work if i'm trying it this way?